# Groovy Error while trying to split a String

Tags: string, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm trying to split a String at each `'{'`.
My String looks like `{RANDOM:4{LETTER:5}}`

As far as I know, I should use `String.split()` function.

My codes looks like:

```java
public static String replaceParams(String str) {
    System.out.println(str.split("{"));
}
```

Here comes the problem.

The error is:

> 2019-06-13 15:33:23.042 ERROR k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass
>   - ❌ Illegal repetition 
>   {
>   2019-06-13 15:33:23.051 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/KeyWordTester
>   FAILED. Reason: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal
>   repetition 
>   {
>     at java_lang_String$split$0.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sgds.util.LoadTester.replaceParams(LoadTester.groovy:126)     at
>   com.sgds.util.LoadTester.modifyFile(LoadTester.groovy:144)    at
>   com.sgds.util.LoadTester.invokeMethod(LoadTester.groovy)  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:50)
>     at KeyWordTester.run(KeyWordTester:16)  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
>     at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   TempTestCase1560432797559.run(TempTestCase1560432797559.groovy:21)

I searched in my whole code and I assure you that there is no `{` not closed.

First thing I did as I thought it was compiler syntax checker problem, I tried replacing my `{` by its ascii value like that:

```java
System.out.println(str.split(Character.toString((char)123)))
```

Does not work either...

Do you know where the problem may come from?

Comment: I never used Groovy so what I tell may be irrelevant, but in Java `split` uses regex (regular expressions) where `{` is considered as start of `{n}` or `{n,m}` *quantifier*, for instance like `a{3}` represents `aaa`. To make it simple character you need to *escape* it. In Java you can use `spit("\\{")` to escape it manually, or `split(Pattern.quote("{"))` to let [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) generate regex which represents `{` as literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using Groovy's native regexp syntax:

```
def res = '{RANDOM:4{LETTER:5}}'.split( /[\{\}]/ )
assert ['', 'RANDOM:4', 'LETTER:5'] == res
```

Also, I don't think that `split()` is what you really need. Based on your data you'd rather want:

```
String txt = '{RANDOM:4{LETTER:5}}'
def res = [:]
txt.eachMatch( /[\{\}]?([A-Z]+):(\d+)[\{\}]?/ ){ res[ it[ 1 ] ] = it[ 2 ].toInteger() }
assert [RANDOM:4, LETTER:5] == res
```

Comment: You only need `.split( /[{}]/ )`

Comment: Another way: `txt.findAll(/([A-Z]+):(\d+)/).collectEntries { it.split(':', 2) }`

Answer (score 1):

The { and } are special in Java's regex dialect (and most other dialects for that matter): they are the opening and closing tokens for the repetition quantifier {n,m} where n and m are integers. Hence the error message: "Illegal repetition".

You should escape them:

```
public static String replaceParams(String str) {
    System.out.println(str.split("\\{"));
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: `}` is not always special in Java and doesn't require escaping. For instance regex like `a{2}}` represents string `aa}` because last `}` isn't part of any quantifier `{..}`.